# Do you think this transition Matrix is correct?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Here is the situation we are trying to model:

given a car that has 3 states, labeled 1, 2 and 3.

**state 1:** is when the vehicle is in good operating condition.

**state 2:** repairs may be required to return to state 1 or it can be left as it is.

**state 3:** the vehicle is totaled and needs replacement.

We are told that the daily states follow a Markov chain with transition matrix

$P =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
.25 & .75 & 0 \\
0 & .5 & .5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $

I am having problem with this matrix. Line 1 should be for state 1 and so forth and so on. But based on the givens, this seems incorrect. For instance according to the matrix $Pr[state2 \rightarrow state1] = 0$. Not according to the data.

Answer (score 0):

To me,
state 2 should be
.5 .5 0.
This assumes that
there is no chance
a vehicle being repaired
would be totaled.

Answer (score 0):

State 1 is 0.75 0.5 0.

State 2 is 0.5 0.5 0.

State 3 is 0  0  1.

Since there is gradual deterioration from State 1 to State 3.